# How can I move the Detail section of Crystal Report to Second Page?

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I have a Crystal Report which has a very long initial text. If I increase the text the crystal report gives message "the page header is too long". I just want that the tabular section start from next page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply allow the details section to grow,just tick on the CanGrow properties of the details section, it will automatically let the contains flow to the next page.

**Complete procedure:**

Page footers don't resize, so you can't easily do what you want.

Here's a hack that, while far, far from ideal, may help:

Add a section that will repeat with every detail row (something like your primary key), and suppress the group header.
Create a formula with the following contents:  shared numbervar recordcount := recordcount + 1; and put it in your new group footer.
Create another formula that resets the variable: shared numbervar recordcount := 0; and put it in the page footer.
Open the section expert and choose your new group footer. Choose "Print at Bottom of Page". In the suppress formula use: shared numbervar recordcount; recordcount < 50 // Magic Number Alert
Add your page footer text to the group footer
This will print the group footer at the bottom of the page after every 50 records have printed. The group footer will expand to fit the text in your field.

I'm thinking that you could make the magic number vary according to the length of your footer text, so your suppression formula would be recordcount < (if length({my.field}) > 100 then 25 else 50; or something like that, which would vary the number of records before a page break according to your text length.